# equation in minipage can't be numbered in the same line

Tags: equations, minipage

I want to have my long equation autowrap in different page size, although it is not in good looking but at least it is readable. So this is my example

```
\documentclass[a6paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}    

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}

\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}\centering\begin{math}
y(x,\boldsymbol{w})=w_{0}+w_{1}x+w_{2}x^2+\ldots+w_{M}x^M=\sum_{j=0}^{M} w_{j}x^j
\end{math}\end{minipage}\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

But result is that the numbering of equation could not be in the same line of wrapped last part. Is there any fix for it?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Note that `\LARGE` is a switch, not an environment. To reduce code clutter, consider (a) replacing `\begin{LARGE}` with `\LARGE` and (b) omitting `\end{LARGE}`.

Answer (score 3):

I completely have no idea why you are using such a large number of environments. Btw your paper size is not A6, because `a6paper` is ignored by `article`.

I *strongly* prefer this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}    

\begin{document}
\begin{LARGE}

\begin{align}
y(x,\boldsymbol{w})&=w_{0}+w_{1}x+w_{2}x^2+\ldots+w_{M}x^M\nonumber\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{M} w_{j}x^j
\end{align}

\end{LARGE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why the `w` is made bold: maybe it is vector with comopents w_0, w_1, ...

Comment: @Zarko Thanks, got it. Actually I thought the `w`s on the right hand side don't have subscript - I may need another glasses...

Comment: Thank for all of your comments. The way you purpose is to split the equation manually, while in my case I have hundreds of pages tex script which is fit for A4 paper. I just want to turn it into an A6 size which is for kindle reader without needing to go thru and revising thousands of equations, though my paper setting is not actually A6 as you said but it works the same way.

The code in my post is the way I tried many times searching internet, it nearly works as I expected...

Comment: @ajee It is impossible. That is the effect of paper size changing. If you don't want to scale the whole page, there must be some equations which exceed the margin or have a bad looking etc. You _must_ do a revision to all of your equations (even your text, figures, and literally everything) if you change to a5 or a6 without scaling the text.

Comment: Yes you are right, it has some bad looking. The equation doesn't beak up in correct place and doesn't align well. Anyway with this ugly stuff ( using sed to append "\begin{gathered}..." to "\begin equation" in a batch), I could get this pdf readable in kindle.

Comment: @ajee I have this idea: Reformat all your text equations etc in the _smallest_ paper size. After that "upgrading" to larger paper size won't cause much harm.

Comment: addendum to my explanation above: it doesn't work for those which are already in split env, but in my case there is few.

Answer (score 3):

as supplement to nice @JouleV answer.

- `LARGE` is not an environment but switch. for limiting its validity you need to insert it in desired group
- use of `minipage` in your case add only clutter to your equation, which also make unnecessary complications
- you might consider other `amsmath` math environments, for example `split`, which gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[low-sup]{subdepth} % for nicer positions of indices

\usepackage{lipsum}            % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum*[66]
\begin{equation}\LARGE         % it works because follows another environment
    \begin{split}
y(x,\bm{w})
    & = w_{0}+w_{1}x+w_{2}x^2+\ldots+w_{M}x^M   \\
    & = \sum_{j=0}^{M} w_{j}x^j
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```